# Parse html element with lxml / xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

Using lxml/python and xpath, I retrieved the value betwen my  tags. 
I would like to get the html properties too, not just the text, my programme works, but skipped two lines.

python :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import lxml.html
htmltree = lxml.html.parse('data.html')
res = htmltree.xpath("//table[@class='mainTable']/tr/td/text()")
print '\n'.join(res).encode("latin-1")
```

data.html sample

```
<table class='mainTable'>
         <TR>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">235</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc"> Windows XP / Office 2003.</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">
                  G:\REMI\projets\Migration_XP_Office2003\Procedures\Installation Win XP et Office 2003.doc</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">2005-10-18</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">2010-12-30</TD></TR>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">
                  <P class="MsoBodyText" 
                    style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><STRONG><FONT face="Times New Roman" size="5">blablablablablablbala<BR><BR></FONT></STRONG></FONT></P>
                  </TD>
                <TR>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">23</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">XEROX/ MAC</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">
                    <P>joint.</P>
                    <P>&nbsp;</P></TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">G:\DDTH_INF\REMI\bdcfiles\I098_Page_de_garde_MAC.doc</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">2012-12-19</TD>
                  <TD bgcolor="#cccccc">2012-12-19</TD>
         </TR>
 </table>
```

return :

```
 235 Windows XP / Office 2003.
 G:\REMI\projets\Migration_XP_Office2003\Procedures\Installation Win XP
 et Office 2003.doc 2005-10-18 2010-12-30

 23 XEROX/ MAC G:\DDTH_INF\REMI\bdcfiles\I098_Page_de_garde_MAC.doc
 2012-12-19 2012-12-19
```

I dont understand why the programm skipped

```
<P class="MsoBodyText" 
                        style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"><STRONG><FONT face="Times New Roman" size="5">blablablablablablbala<BR><BR></FONT></STRONG></FONT></P>
```

and

```
 <P>joint.</P>
                        <P>&nbsp;</P>
```

Because it's between `<p>` tag ? I just want to get all the data between each TD.  I tried with /tr/td/p/  too but it's not the solution.

note: this code is a sample, its possible that html is broken, but my file is well structured.

Comment: try `res = htmltree.xpath("//table[@class='mainTable']/tr/td//text()")`to grab  all child text nodes.

Comment: Just a simple remark: only use lxml for html pages that contain **correct** html. You could find in many places unclosed tags that lxml won't be able to process (in fact only use it if **you** wrote the HTML...). If unsure, use BeautifulSoup with is great at fixing such (minor) errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are getting the `text()` out of each `td` element - which basically means - *give me a text node located directly inside the `td` element*.

Instead, call [`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) on every `td` found:

```
texts = [td.text_content() for td in htmltree.xpath("//table[@class='mainTable']/tr/td")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, I understand better, I started to used xpath just today, i'm still a beginer, thank for the precision about how text() method means exactly.